# How to save and display image in database using java Spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, database, model-view-controller

I try to save in database image, I added to my db field image with data type longblob, now I looking for way to save it. To my html file i have input type file, and when i try to save i have error like this.

```
Field error in object 'item' on field 'image': rejected value [thumb-252577.png]; codes [typeMismatch.item.image,typeMismatch.image,typeMismatch.[Ljava.lang.Byte;,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [item.image,image]; arguments []; default message [image]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Byte[]' for property 'image'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "thumb-252577.png"]]
```

i have object item.java with

```
    private Byte[] image;
```

and my controller looks like this

```
@PostMapping(value = "/items/add")
    public String itemAddPost(Model model, HttpSession session, @ModelAttribute("item") item item, ){
        User isExist= (User) session.getAttribute("loggedUser");
        if (null == isExist){
            return "index";
        }
        item.setWhoAdd(isExist.getId());
        System.out.println(item.getImage());
        itemRepository.save(item);
        return "redirect:/items";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When I understand the error message correctly you send `thumb-252577.png` as String to your backend and the parser obviously could not convert that into a byte array. So you have to check what data do you send to your spring RestController.